# Gzip files only above certain bytes in Terminal

Tags: linux, compression, gzip

I type this command that finds all css files in a folder (including sub-folders) and gzips them individually. Here's the command:

```
find . -type f -name "*.css" -exec sh -c "gzip -9v < {} > {}.gz" \;
```

How do I tell it to only gzip files above certain size?

Comment: Use the `-size` option to `find`, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name "*.css" -size +1M -exec sh -c "gzip -9v < {} > {}.gz" \;
```

will only compress files that are at least 1 MB.